# Possible number of terms in an Arithmetic Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, quadratics, arithmetic-progressions

The sum of the first $n$ $(n>1)$ terms of the A.P. is $153$ and the common difference is $2$. If the first term is an integer , then number of possible values of $n$ is

$a)$ $3$

$b)$ $4$

$c)$ $5$

$d)$ $6$

My approach : I used the formula for the first $n$ terms of an A.P. to arrive at the following quadratic equation 
$n^2 + n(a-1) -153 = 0 $

Next up I realised that since we are talking about the number of terms , thus the 
possible values which n can take must be whole numbers. That is the discriminant of the above quadratic should yield a whole number in other words

$ (a-1)^2 + 612 = y^2 $ for some y .

However I am stuck at this point , as from here I am unable to figure out the number of such a's ( i.e. the initial terms of an AP ) which will complete the required pythagorean triplet
The answer mentioned is $5$

Please let me know , if I am doing a step wrong somewhere . Or If you have a better solution , that will be welcomed too.

Comment: Hint:  from your discriminant form we see that $612=y^2-(a-1)^2=(y-b)(y+b)$  where we have written $b=a-1$.  Since everything is an integer we just need to look for ways to write $612=cd$ where $c,d$ are both even.

Comment: Hmm so I tried using your approach and could come up with only two distinct pairs of numbers such that both c and d are even , which were 306 & 2  and 102 & 6 . Now what , how do we conclude that n can take five different values from this ?

Comment: You are missing the pair $(18,34)$.  I get one solution for each pair...with starting points $9,49,153$.  Don't see any others (but possibly I am missing something).

Comment: @lulu That's what I got (see my "answer"), yet I then get $\;n=9\;$ and this doesn't show as option.

Comment: @Joanpemo  Well...I get three solutions, with $n=\{9,2,1\}$.  That's three solutions so I get the answer $3$.

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava I can't see how the answer is $\;n=5\;$ , since then your quadratic becomes $$25+5(a-1)=153\implies 5(a-1)=128$$ yet $128$ isn't divisible by $5$

Comment: @Joanpemo  To be precise, my three solutions are the progressions $\{153\},\;\{49,51,53\},\;\{9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25\}$.  The problem is asking for the number of solutions....not any value attached to a particular solution.

Comment: @lulu So I see...perhaps you're missing the possibility of *negative* first term?

Comment: This is a rather annoying question. Perhaps it has some educative/mathematical value, but I can't see it...

Comment: @Joanpemo  Agreed as to the nature of the question.  My method, following that of the OP, solved for the first term in the progression.  I think that ought to give all of them...

Comment: @Joanpemo I was preparing for an entrance exam to one of India's best Mathematical institutes , that where I come across this , sadly in the question bank provided by them , I can only see the answer no solution.

Comment: @Joanpemo  You are right!  There are some with negative starting points as well.  $-7$ is a possible starting point,  as are $-47, -151$.

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava  Having chosen a pair $c,d$ both even with $612=cd$ we can solve for $y$, in your notation, and then $a-1=y-c$ OR $y-d$.  I ignored all the negative values for $a$ for no good reason.  That gives $6$ solutions.  I'll bet the bank ignores the "degenerate" solution corresponding to $\{153\}$. Indeed, you specify $n>1$ so I should have rejected that one.

Comment: @lulu Way to go ! +1\

Comment: @lulu Thanks so much . I would be great i you could formulate this as an answer. Then I could close the question .

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava  I just posted it.  Good luck on your exam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the (extensive) discussion in the comments:

The OP's method is sound and nearly complete.  To finish it off we look at the relation $$612=y^2-(a-1)^2=(y+(a-1))(y-(a+1)$$  To solve that (over the integers) we simply need to factor $612=cd$ where the factors must have the same parity.  There are three possible such factorings:  $$\{18,34\},\;\{2,306\},\:\{6,102\}$$

Each of these gives rise to two possible starting points for our progressions.  We get $$a\in \{-151,-47,-7,9,49,153\}$$

We reject the "degenerate" case $a=153$ as that progression just has a single term (and the OP specified $n>1$).  Thus we have $5$ solutions.

Answer (score 1):

one of the possible value of $n$ is $3$.

**REASON**

Let the first term of $AP$ be $a-2$.

$AP: a-2, a, a+2,a+4,a+6,a+8,a+10,\cdots$

Sum of first three terms of $AP= 3a$ which will give $a=51$(integer value).

Now generalising this pattern

we get other possible values of $n$ are $9,17,51,153$

As when we get odd number of terms say, $2k+1$

We can take $AP$ to be $a-2k,a-2(k-1),a-2(k-2),\cdots,a,a+2,a+4,\cdots,a+2(k-1),a+2k\cdots$

(Note: I have mentioned first $2k+1$ terms here)

On adding all these we get $a(2k+1)$ (as common difference will cancel each other due to negative pairity)

Thus $a(2k+1)=153\Rightarrow a=\frac{153}{2k+1}$ ,for integral value of $a, 2k+1$ has to be a positive factor of $153$ which are $5$(excluding 1).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question (+$1$).

As the common difference is $2$, the series is either one of odd numbers or even numbers only. As the sum is an odd number, it must be a series of odd numbers  with an odd number of terms. This narrows it down to $3$ terms or $5$ terms from the choices given.

Since $153\div 3=51$, a quick check shows that $49+51+53=153$ hence the answer is $3.\;\blacksquare$

NB: $153\div 5\approx 30$. The four closest odd numbers to $30$ add up to $120$, and the next one is either $25$ or $35$, none of which would result in $153$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
   n^2 +(a-1)n - 153 &= 0 \\
   (n+u)(n-v) &= 0 \\
   n^2 + (u-v)n - uv &= 0
\end{align}

So you need two positive integers, say $u>v>0$, such that $uv=153$ and $u-v=a-1$. Which will have solution $n=v$.

There aren't that many possibilities

\begin{array}{|rr|r|rr|}
\hline
   u & v & u-v & a & n \\
\hline
   153 & 1 & 152 & 153 & 1 \\
    51 & 3 &  48 &  49 & 3 \\
    17 & 9 &   8 &   9 & 9 \\
\hline
\end{array}

---

Above I was assuming $a > 1$. If you allow $a$ to be a negative number, then the analysis changes a bit.

$$n^2 +(a-1)n - 153 = 0$$

The divisors of $153$ are $1,3,9,17,51,153$ We find the following.

\begin{array}{|l|rr|}
\hline
   \text{factors} & a & n\\ 
\hline
   (n-1)(n+153) = n^2+152n - 153 &  153 &   1 \\
   (n-3)(n+ 51) = n^2 +48n - 153 &   49 &   3 \\ 
   (n-9)(n+17)  = n^2  +8n - 153 &    9 &   9 \\
   (n-17)(n+9)  = n^2  -8n - 153 &   -7 &  17 \\
   (n-51)(n+3)  = n^2 -48n - 153 &  -47 &  51 \\
   (n-153)(n+1) = n^2-152n - 153 & -151 & 153 \\
\hline
\end{array}